# Creating a function called IFTRUE that behaves as IFERROR but for a function returning TRUE. Worsheetfunction.if doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, code

I wanted to create a custom function that would be a shorthand for `if(somefunction(arg)=something,"sometext",somefunction(arg))` So I don't have to duplicate `somefunction(arg)` each time I do this, just like how `iferror` lets us do away with `if(iserror(somefunction(arg)),"sometext",somefunction(arg)`

For example, I want to be able to type `iftrue(somefunction(arg),"=A1","message")` and that to be equivalent to `if(sumfunction(arg)=A1,"message",sumfunction(arg))`

I tried:

```
Function iftrue(Fx, condition, show)
    iftrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.if(Fx & condition, show, Fx)
End Function
```

But it gives #value.

---

*To diagnose my problem, I tried some simpler functions, to see where I was going wrong.  So I duplicated the SUM and If functions.*

*This "sum" function works.*

```
Function testsum(a, b)
    test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(a, b)
End Function
```

*But this "if" function doesn't work.*

```
Function testif(a, b, c)
    testif = Application.WorksheetFunction.if(a, b, c)
End Function
```

So I think my problem is the way I'm invoking the `worksheet.function.if`.

I know I could just get around this by using VBA ifs instead but that's not really what I want to do.

Comment: please give an example of `iftrue`'s parameters which you've tried and wasn't working. What doesn't work mean? Wrong output / error message?

Comment: I had to do some parsing to deal with text.  Please see my edit.  It will work with formulas that return text as well as numbers,  It will return a string.

Comment: It will now return the same as what the function returns.  If the function returns a double so will this function.  If it returns text so will this function.  You may need to refresh the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Application.WorksheetFunction.If()`

Even if there was you would still need to push extra quotes into the test part of the if.  for example if the fx resolved to `"test"` and condition was `"=test"` the resultant string would be `"test = test"`

Put that

So use Evaluate instead.

We need to parse the string in a certain format for Evaluate.

we need to push extra quotes into the resultant string.  for example if the fx resolved to `"test"` and condition was `"=test"` the resultant string would be `"test = test"`.

Putting this in Evaluate, the function would look for a function named `test`.  So we need a string that is like `""test"="test""`, which will resolve to True.

If the condition was **always** an equality and never an inequality we could simply use `IF fx = condition then` in place of everything up to and including `If tst Then`.

This function is more dynamic than that as it allows inequalities:

```
Function IFTrue(fx, condition As String, show)
Dim tst As Boolean
Dim z As Integer
Dim t As String
'test whether the condition is assuming "="
If InStr("<>=", Left(condition, 1)) = 0 Then condition = "=" & condition
'Find whether there is one or two qulifiers
If InStr("<>=", Mid(condition, 2, 1)) > 0 Then z = 2 Else z = 1
'Parse string to remove qulifiers from the quotes and make everything a string
t = """" & fx & """" & Left(condition, z) & """" & Mid(condition, z + 1) & """"
'evaluate the formula string to resolve to True or False
tst = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(t)

If tst Then
    IFTrue = show
Else
    IFTrue = fx
End If
End Function
```

You would then call it like this

```
=IFtrue(SUM(A1,A2),"=A3","Must Be True")
```

---

Edit

You can use the IIF() and reduce the number of lines

```
Function IFTrue2(fx, condition As String, show)
Dim z As Integer

'test whether the condition is assuming "="
If InStr("<>=", Left(condition, 1)) = 0 Then condition = "=" & condition
'Find whether there is one or two qulifiers
If InStr("<>=", Mid(condition, 2, 1)) > 0 Then z = 2 Else z = 1

IFTrue2 = IIf(Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate("""" & fx & """" & Left(condition, z) & """" & Mid(condition, z + 1) & """"), show, fx)

End Function
```

Comment: ____________Very Nice_________

Comment: @Gary'sStudent now it will return the same type as what the input is.

Comment: I'll put this in my toolbox.

Comment: This has grown since I last looked!  I like that it doesn't require the argument as a string any more.  Could you comment this code please?  While it's better than it was before, it's now a little opaque.

Comment: I don't mean to sound ungrateful, but is there no way of using the built-in excel if function, and simply refactoring the way the arguments are passed to that?  Rather than building a function from scratch as you have here.

Comment: No, there is no way.  What I did not add is that there is no WorksheetFunction.If. So we need to build the string.  I have added notes and simplified the function.  As I was adding notes I realized I over worked the function and this simpler function still does what is desired. @Some_Guy